# Including UWP project in WPF project raises runtime errors

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, shared-libraries

Project I work on need to show UWP control from UWP library inside of WPF window. 
Here is the document page on which I had based my work (check section for adding custom UWP control):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/windowsxamlhost#add-a-custom-uwp-control

Had setup WPF window and it shows standard UWP controls (like button) at the runtime just fine. However, when I include UWP project, WPF window throws exception at start (at the moment of context initialization of EF).

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
```

Sqlite version I'm using is 1.0.88.0 and EF is 5. But it doesn't make any sense that it clashes with these libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ffixed an issue on startup by updating SQLite package to 1.0.111.0 and EF to version 6.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

> Including UWP project in WPF project raises runtime errors

Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/windowsxamlhost#add-a-custom-uwp-control), I create sample project. When build the project, it throw many errors that lost assembly. After add the `Windows.winmd` file every thing work well. You could try to add the `Windows.winmd` file where in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd` to WPF app reference.

**Detail steps**

Right click project References -> Add References -> Browse(file type all file)-> select **Windows.winmd**

And this sample project that you could refer [this](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/WPFWithUWPTest).

Comment: Nico, I have done that already. You can check out my initial post, it works when I use standard UWP controls (like UWP Button). Had also included necessary references as described in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#first-set-up-your-project

Comment: Correct, But I follow the document and create sample project, And it works well, I could not reproduce your issue.

Comment: Your project also does the same as mine project - and that works fine. However, after adding references to SqlLite and EF, UWP code breaks up in runtime when EF context has initilized. Did you tried that?

Comment: I have not add EF to the project.

Comment: I have fixed an issue on startup by updating SQLite package to 1.0.111.0 and EF to version 6.2.0.