# Calling CameraCaptureUI from Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

I'd like to be able to call the UWP class, Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI from a winforms application.

I've been looking at the Microsoft Community Toolkit, along with other options, like DirectShow, but nothing compares to the Windows 10 media capture class.  It seems as though the Community Toolkit was partially built around interoperability of winforms and UWP, but I can't find any reference to the CameraCaptureUI in the documentation or how to call it generically from a winform.

The following code works wonderfully within a UWP application:

```
CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
Size aspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);
dialog.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;
StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.PhotoOrVideo);
StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;

if (file != null) await file.MoveAsync(folder);
```

It gives a camera dialog, rather than just showing the camera UI.  I'd like to call this code from a legacy-style winforms app.  Has anyone else solved this issue?

To clarify:  My client wants to use a winforms app on a Surface Pro device.  The device has two cameras, one forward facing and one "selfy"-style camera.  The solution would need to encompass both, preferably, which is why I love the idea of making use of the built-in Windows 10 camera UI.

Answer (score 1):

Derive from this case [reply](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0d6c92d7-9f75-4772-b3c7-b49b78e1fefe/is-it-possible-to-access-windowsmediacapturecameracaptureui-from-windows-forms). `CameraCaptureUI` class is not available for WinForm app.
For capturing photo please use MediaCapture class, which is available  WinForms app, This is [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit) For camera preview UI you could refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/windowsxamlhost#add-a-custom-uwp-control)

Comment: Hi Nico.  This is a good answer, and I should have clarified more in my question.  My customer wants to use a windows form application on a new Surface Pro device.  My concern with using MediaCapture, rather than the built-in camera UI is that it won't have a way to control the camera selection, moving from the "selfy shot" to the forward facing camera.  That's why I was so enamored with the CamerCaptureUI's dialog.  It seems perfect, and would launch the Surface Pro's built-in camera.

What are your thoughts on that issue?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please check this [line](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit/cs/MainPage.xaml.cs#L220), if you want to use front camera, please set parameter as `Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front`. And if the answer is helpful please mark it thx.

Comment: Hi Nico, I think I'm missing something.  Several of the answers you've given, including that last link reference Windows Universal solutions (UWP), which I can't use in a winforms application.  The line of code you just references in part of a solution that imports Windows.Media.Capture (a UWP assembly).  I'd really like to be able to use it, but again, this is for a winforms app.  From what I've seen, I can't reference that assembly.  Am I misunderstanding something??

Comment: Please check this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57320656/7254781) and add Windows.winmd to project reference.